# How to add/remove data from a list view (Android)?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm using a list view to displace names. The user needs to be able to add a name to the bottom of the list view and to be able to delete names within. The names are saved using SharedPreferences and loaded into an original string array which I then load to an ArrayAdapter. The problem with this method is that, unless I fill up the entire string array, I get a NPE for the ArrayAdapter. So my solution was to set the string array to only be as big as the number of names. This means, however, that I cannot add a name to the list, as the list is only so long.

What's the best way to be able to add and remove strings from a list view and still be able to tell what they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing values of `listview` data please put code

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `List<T>` overload rather than the static array for the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.  Then you can add or remove items to your `List<T>` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` once you are done.  Using a dynamic data structure like a `List<T>` will avoid any NPE.